# Spring Data:: Making Repository Methods Available in Service Interfaces

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring Data and JPA/Hibernate for my repositories. When I extend JpaRepository, I get many methods as usual as it implements PagingAndSortingRepository and CrudRepository.

Am using the repositories inside my service classes. My question now is, is there a way I can get all the methods in the repositories inside my service interfaces so that the service implmenting classes can delegate the calls to the repositories using the same method names as the repositories.

I would like to use the same method names as the repository methods and also don't want to call my repositories directly from the controllers.

Do I have to copy all the method signatures from the JpaRepository,  PagingAndSortingRepository and CrudRepository into my service interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood the question right.Firstly create repository as an interface that extends JpaRepository or others and do not forget annotate your interface with @Repository. Then create your service and inject your repository to it, so you can create your own methods(any name can be used) in a service. Then you can inject service to your controller. This technic mostly used.

Comment: Why not just declare your own methods inside the repository interface? That is what Spring Data JPA recommends. It will save a lot of time.

Comment: I know we can put our own methods in a repository, i just gave the simplest usage for spring data

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood what a `Service` really represents.
A `Service` is the point where to handle business logic. Its methods should represent business operations, not simply data-retrieval/persistence ones.

Simply having all the `JpaRepository` methods and delegating to a `Repository` is a recipe for massive code duplication, which you should avoid.

Build your `Service` along your business requirements.
If you feel there is no need to have a Service middleware, maybe because you only get/set data, simply `Autowire` the `Repository` inside your `Controller`.

It's not always true that using a `Repository` inside a `Controller` is wrong. It depends.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to copy the methods of `Repository` to any service. Spring Data JPA offers many powerful features to write custom queries.

Suppose you have `UserRepository` for a domain called `User` and want to find a user by his/her email address. Instead of creating `findByEmail` method in a separate service that extends `UserRepository`, just declare it inside the `UserRepository` interface:

```java
User findByEmail(String email);
```

Spring Data JPA will then do all the dirty work for you. You can call this method by injecting `UserRepository` inside the `Controller` (or other classes).

Above is only a simple example. You can even declare a query with multiple conditions:

```java
User findByEmailOrUsername(String email, String username);

User findByEmailAndActiveTrue(String email);

List<User> findTop10ByEmail();
```

I would suggest you to explore the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) of Spring Data JPA. There are so many things you can do by writing few lines of code.